# Add percentage sign to dataframe values

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have a quick question. I have a dataframe that I'm using in a dashboard which shows rowwise percentages. I've calculated this using the (second line of) code below, but I would really like a percentage sign after each row (except for the row 'count' of course). It's just for visual purposes of the dashboard, so I've tried finding out if I can just paste/paste0 the '%'-sign in there, but without luck. Any suggestions? Much appreciated!

**Dataframe:**

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(0,40), 20, replace=T ), 4, 5))
df <- rowPercents(df, digits = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the `%` sign to `df` :

```
df[] <- paste0(as.matrix(df), '%')
df
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
#1  2% 28%  0%  3% 14%
#2 32% 16%  1% 20%  0%
#3  4% 36% 32% 26% 31%
#4 14% 38% 16%  9% 40%
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, thank you! That really helped. I was just wondering: I want to do this to every colum except for the last one. I know I can fix this by specifying df[, 1:4]) in the above mentioned example. However, I'm using the table in an interactive dashboard and there is one matrix entry that has less columns. My question: Is there a way to say 'except for the last column', without specifying the numbers of the columns?

Comment: Yes except last column can be specified with `df[-ncol(df)]`. So here you can use it as `df[-ncol(df)] <- paste0(as.matrix(df[-ncol(df)]), '%')`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` as this would be more efficient column wise

```
df[] <- lapply(df, paste0, '%')
```